# cols_label in gt table inside function

Tags: r, gt

is there a solution to have column names in cols_label as strings?

Like

```
fun <- function( df,column, label )
{
  df %>%
    gt() %>%
    cols_label( column = label)
  
}


fun( mtcars,"cyl", "cylinder")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the curly-curly operator.

```
library(gt)

fun <- function(df, column, label)
{
  df %>%
    gt() %>%
    cols_label({{column}} := label)
}

fun(mtcars, "cyl", "cylinder")
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `.list` parameter. This will handle vectors of columns.

```
library(gt)

fun <- function(df, column, label)
{
  cols_list = as.list(label) %>% purrr::set_names(column)
  
  df %>%
    gt() %>%
    cols_label(.list = cols_list)
}

fun(mtcars, "cyl", "cylinder")
fun(mtcars, c("cyl", "hp"), c("cylinder", "horsepower"))
```

Comment: thanks, and if column is a vector of columns? I did some tests and I get "`arg` must be a symbol"

Comment: You can use the `.list` parameter. I've updated my answer.