# How to include both column names and column labels for sas datasets at the top of table in gt tables in r?

Tags: r, gt

**1. Query**
I am using `sas` datasets (sas datasets contain labels that can be read `labelled::get_variable_labels(df)`)  and trying to create `gt` table that can have both **column name** and **labels** at the top of data. But I am not sure how to do that and nor able to find anything relevant on net.

By default `gt` is using `lables` as the header of the data.

[image]

data

```
df %>% head()
# A tibble: 6 × 357
  SPOUSARR SPOUSE NRESPOUS HHSPOUSE SPOUSEFW SPOUSENF HHKID
     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       NA      0       NA        0       NA       NA     0
2       NA      0       NA        0       NA       NA     0
3       NA      1        3        0       NA       NA     0
4       NA      0       NA        0       NA       NA     6
5       NA      1        0        1       NA       NA     2
6       NA      1        3        0       NA       NA     4
```

below code gives me the label names in the dataset:

```
labelled::get_variable_labels(df)

$SPOUSARR
[1] "YEAR SPOUSE ARRIVAL IN US"

$SPOUSE
[1] "SPOUSE ON FAMILY GRID"

$NRESPOUS
[1] "NON HH RESIDENT SPOUSE"

$HHSPOUSE
[1] "SPOUSE IN HH"
```

**2. Desired output:** **Structure of table** that I am trying to achieve is like below:
[image]

**3. Sample data Source** used in this post is **downloaded** from this [data link](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ETA/naws/pdfs/naws_all.zip) government source https://www.dol.gov/agencies/eta/national-agricultural-workers-survey/data/files-sas.

**4. packages & code used:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(gt)
library(labelled)

# after download & unzipping 15mb file
df <- haven::read_sas("naws_all.sas7bdat")

# to view table
df %>% head() %>% gt()

# to view lables
labelled::get_variable_labels(df)
```

Would really Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking `fun()` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717445/20002111), we can try

```r
# downloading and preparing data
if(exists("hasRun") == FALSE) {
  temp = tempfile()
  temp2 = tempfile()
  download.file("https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ETA/naws/pdfs/naws_all.zip", temp) 
  unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
  df = haven::read_sas(file.path(temp2, list.files(temp2)))
  unlink(c(temp, temp2))
  hasRun = TRUE 
}
X = df[1:3, 1:3]

fun = \(df, column, label) {
  cols_list = as.list(label) |> setNames(column)
  df |> 
    gt::gt() |>
    gt::cols_label(.list = cols_list, .fn = gt::md) |>
    gt::cols_align(align = "left")
}
fun(X, colnames(X), 
    paste0(colnames(X), "<br>", labelled::get_variable_labels(X)))
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Friede, really appreciate your help. I though we need to include `.process units = TRUE` for `<br>` execution but it worked. In large number of columns with big labels is there a way to streamline column names in clean 1 line/row ? When I am running it on 15 columns it losses its streamlined layout

Comment: No. `.fn = gt::md` is needed. I don't think so. Who can display "*a large number of columns with big labels*"?

Comment: we needed to and already using `reactable` for this but we thought `gt` is faster so was trying to replicate same in gt but it is not aesthetically pleasing and also taking more time than redactable with both column names & labels.